# Modal window closes on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in a bootstrap modal window and what is happening, is when I click the 'send' button, the modal closes and a white page displays the result of my action call to contact-form.php and shows the error message for blank field but thid should be showing in the message div in the form in the the modal window.

I am obviously doing something fundementally wrong and would appreciate any help you can offer. I wouls have done a snippet but couldn't see how to include php code.
Many thanks

Bootstrap V3.3.7

**UPDATE:** The form works fine if i use as normal form outside of the modal
window.

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h2 class="modal__title"><div style="color: white; margin-top: -14px; margin-left: 36px;">Contact Us</div></h2>
        <div style="color: white; margin-left: 36px; margin-bottom: 20px;">If you need to contact us, please use this form and we shall respond as soon as possible. Thanks</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="content-block contact-3">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">        
            <div class="col-md-9">           
              <div id="contact" class="form-container">

                  <div id="message"></div> <-ERROR SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE
                  <form method="post" action="js/contact-form.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Message" id="textArea"></textarea>
                      <div class="editContent">
                        <p class="small text-muted"><span class="guardsman">* All fields are required.</span> Once we receive your message we will respond as soon as possible.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" class="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="cf-submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>

              </div>
              <!-- /.form-container -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
      </div>
      <!--// END Contact 3-1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

contact-form.php

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($phone) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Phone number can only contain digits and no spaces.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have entered an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "yourname@yourdomain.com";

$address = "yourname@yourdomain.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name from your website, their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name by email, $email or by phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h2>Email Sent Successfully.</h2>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been sent to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

?>

sendmail.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  $('#contactform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").fadeOut(500, function () {
      $('#message').hide();

      $.post(action, {
          name: $('#name').val(),
          email: $('#email').val(),
          phone: $('#phone').val(),
          comments: $('#comments').val(),
        },
        function (data) {
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
          $('#message').slideDown('slow');
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
          if (data.match('success') != null) {
            $('#contactform').fadeOut('slow');
            $("#message").delay(3000).fadeOut();
            $("#contactform").delay(4000).fadeIn();
            $("#contactform").css("margin-top", "40px !important");
            $("#contactform").trigger("reset");
          }
        }
      );

    });

    return false;

  });

});
```

Comment: go step by step and add some `console.log` controllers to see what's going on, you could use also `done` or `fail` to output more or some error (if any). Due to the fact you have a big chunk of code is kind of hard to follow or find your error.

Comment: For some reason, console.log does not display in firebug. I have it enabled. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test you code but in my opinion i would not do the submit action with $(form).submit().... also if you are doing a event.preventDefault(), i explain better, you are doing an ajax call and with different errors you have differents answers, so in your place i would delete the action in the html at on click of the send button i would do an ajax call and manage the answer.Try in this way, because i think that if you use the submit in that way the browser interpret the submit form also because you are using the action url to send the call.

```
    $('#cf-submit').click(function(){

        name = $('#name').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        phone = $('#phone').val();
        comments = $('#comments').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : 'js/contact-form.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                name : name,
                email : email,
                phone : phone,
                comments : comments,
            },
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function(response){
                $('#message').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I shall try to rearrange the code and post back. Thanks

Comment: ok i have edited the message, just to look the procedure, it's working on my computer, for sure deleting the url in the action html and use it in the ajax url and delete the type submit use type button in the html....bye and good days.

Comment: Cheers for that Spizzi. Just the job. happy days

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to put exit(); at the end of file contact-form.php

Comment: you mean before closing ?> tag? Also the form works fine if I use outside of modal window. Thanks

Comment: Yes...  just add exit(); before closing ?>

Comment: Didn't make any difference